# Change type which isn't object to interface

Tags: typescript

I have a type which isn't an object and I want to convert them to interface

```
import { Payload } from './reduxState'

export type ProjectPayload = Payload
```

I have been asked to change this to interface in pr review.

I am not sure how I can change this to interface, Can someone please help me out?

Comment: `interface ProjectPayload extends Payload {}`?

Answer (score 0):

> I have been asked to change this to interface in pr review.

For the Type alias:

```
export type ProjectPayload = Payload
```

The equivalent Interface is:

```
interface ProjectPayload extends Payload {}
```